# Why code under the exception is not executed?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I define my own Exception which look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuuJX.png)

When I run code, exception was raise in line 272, exception is handled in line 281, and this exception was raised but code under the exception was not executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVgy0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8l67.png)

In the next step code jump to line 353 and exception MMM was handled, but never before exception MMM raised. MMM exception is my own exception.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjh2I.png)

Someone know why code under the SendError was not executed?

Answer (score 0):

When I declare My own Exception SendError I made a syntax error wchich python not warn me. I forgot about () after 'super' method.
So no constructor was called, and this my own Exception not be a proper matched in this case.

I declare like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHIZA.png)
By the correctly is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeeZu.png)